# using ffmpeg in C: system() or C api?

Tags: c, shell, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg's transcoding features multiple times in my program. This can be achieved by doing

```
ffmpeg -i input output
```

in a terminal. I believe I can use some shell or C code to execute these commands programmatically.

I could also directly use ffmpeg's c libraries to do this. My question is, will there be a noticeable performance difference between the 2 approaches? Obviously the first will be simpler to implement, but will I pay a big performance cost?

Comment: *"will there be a noticeable performance difference between the 2 approaches?"* I don't think that we can answer that, since we don't know how you are using it. We also don't what you consider *noticeable* enough.

Comment: I suggest that you start with simplest approach that meets your requirements, and then increase complexity if necessary.

Comment: *Obviously the first will be simpler to implement, but will I pay a big performance cost?*  Why is any potential performance improvement important? That's the important question. If what you have now is fast enough, don't bother.  If this is job-related, you can always just buy faster hardware and not spend days or weeks improving software performance when you can just throw faster hardware at the problem.  If you just want to spend some of your own time to find out if you can make it faster, go ahead and try - you'll learn.  FWIW, if you do try, don't ignore the IO.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm going to attempt to use ffmpeg to generate small video files ready to be live streamed over HTTP with HLS. I'm making a live video streaming service for my university final year project. I just want to do the best I'm capable of but also don't want to spend too much time on something if it's not going to really benefit me. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite typical these days to use the executable (**system()**) version even on mobile phones. If time-to-start is not critical for you, don't bother. If it is, consider making ffmpeg executable available for immediate start, e.g. with [prelink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink).